# Using fct_recode inside a function in R

Tags: r, rstudio, tidyverse, forcats

I am trying to use fct_recode in a function & it gives an error 
"Error: `f` must be a factor (or character vector)."

Edit: If I run this then it works directly not sure how to incorporate this in function

```
  df[,"c1"] <- as.character(df$c1)
  df[,"c1"] <- fct_recode(df$c1,
                               "Female" = "2",
                               "Male" = "1")
```

It worked when I changed df[,c1] to df$c1, not sure why & not sure how to build this into my recode function

Code I am trying

```
recode <- function(data, var1) 
  {
       data[,var1]
       data[,var1] <- as.character(data[,var1])
       data[,var1] <- fct_recode(data[,var1],
                                  "Yes" = "1",
                                 "No" = "2")
       data[,var1] <- fct_explicit_na(data[,var1],"No")
       return(data)
  }

recode(df,"c1")
```

Structure of c1 column of df dataset found using below commant (Its a big dataset hence share dput of one column, do let me know if thats a problem)

```
df[,"c1"] %>% head(10) %>% dput()

structure(list(c1 = c(2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2)), notes = c("b15 urinary creatinine is in mg/dl", 
"3", "the province variable is related to province", "the stratum variable is about urban and rural classification"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

str(df$c1) #gives below output
num [1:5610] 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 ...
 - attr(*, "label")= chr "C1"
 - attr(*, "format.stata")= chr "%10.0g"
```

Any reason why the function must be failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when I reference the column using [[ notation, I am not sure why it fails when I use df[,var1] notation but the working code is as below

```
recode <- function(data, var1) 
  {
       data[[var1]] <- as.character(data[[var1]])
       data[[var1]] <- fct_recode(data[[var1]],
                               "Female" = "2",
                               "Male" = "1"
                               )
       data[[var1]] <- fct_explicit_na(data[[var1]],"No")
       return(data[[var1]])
  }

recode(df,"c1")
```